# Delivering IPA for testing purpose

Tags: ios

My Client is demanding IPA file of the app. And they have provided me with development provisioning profile only. They dont want me to use my own developer account. What else i need to generate IPA? Please help me out generating that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alongwith the provisioning profile, you'll need the `.p12` of the developer account certificate that it was created for.

So... they'll need to export their developer account certificate's private key as a `.p12` file.
This can be done via Keychain Access and they can opt to have any or no password while exporting it.

Then, you will need to import this `p12` into your own Keychain Access.
That's it.

Finally, go to your app's build settings and specify the `Code Signing Identity` that will basically be whatever the `p12` you imported and the `Provisioning Profile` that they provided.

Archive and export
:)

Comment: Hey, I am able to archive the IPA. While exporting, I selected Save for Ad-hoc deployment. It is asking for Development team to use for provisioning. What should I do now?

Comment: I am using my client's account. But I dont have their developer account credentials. Can I add mine?

Comment: @Hawk-Eye : well... select the appropriate team then. Some team should work. If... you've imported the `p12` and `provisioning profile` properly that is. That's all I can suggest from my side. And if you don't have access to their developer account then you can't do much.

Comment: @Hawk-Eye : anyways... here's another way of doing things: [Apple doc on Adding Team Admins and Members](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/MemberCenter_Recipes/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers.html). Show them this link and have them add you onto their developer team. Then all you'll need is the `Provisioning Profile` that they provide to you.

Comment: Can I make an IPA with development provisioning profile?

Comment: @Hawk-Eye : Sure, but only those devices that're registered on this development provisioning profile can install the `ipa`. So that means your clients should edit the provisioning profile and add their iOS devices and it would be recommended if they add your iOS device as well.

Comment: @Hawk-Eye : have them log into their apple dev account and then navigate to the [devices section (link)](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action) to add devices (if required). Which... they need to allow in the required [provisioning profile (link)](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action)

Answer (score -1):

They will have to export their **Distribution certificate** and also send you the **Distribution Provisioning profile**.

[Here is an example how to export the distribution certificate](http://www.ironpaper.com/webintel/articles/how-to-share-an-ios-distribution-certificate/)

You'll install the certificate and provisioning profile provided by your client and sign the ipa file with it.

Comment: Distribution profiles are for the purpose of distribution (Its in the name) not for using for development or testing. In other words Distribution profiles are for the App Store.

Comment: Or AD-hoc builds for testing.

Comment: If it was for ad-hoc according to the apple docs they would need an ad-hoc provisioning profile (`"If necessary, Xcode creates a distribution certificate and an ad hoc provisioning profile for you. The name of the ad hoc provisioning profile beings with the text XC:"`) - taken from apple docs under ad-hoc distribution

Comment: Taken from the same document : _About Ad Hoc Provisioning Profiles
An ad hoc provisioning profile is a distribution provisioning profile for iOS apps that allows your app to be installed on designated devices and to use app services without the assistance of Xcode. It’s one of the two types of distribution provisioning profiles that you can create for iOS apps. (You use the other type of distribution provisioning profile later to submit your app to the store.) An ad hoc provisioning profile ensures that test versions of your app aren’t copied and distributed without your knowledge._

Comment: That sounds like something you should be including in your answer does it not so no one questions it like I am. The idea of this is to get you to provide useful information in your answers and you know it so why not provide it.